# How do I get a list of Business Unit IDs for each project?

Tags: autodesk-forge

For example, I want to create a new project with Forge API, but it wants a business_unit_id but its just a UUID string. But where do I find what that string is for each option? It doesnt seem like I can use the normal word, such as Corporate Commercial/Hospitality/etc. I cant find any information on this. I can find a way to query a project's business unit id, but it doesnt give me a list to use when creating a project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API to get business units data is
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/business_units_structure-GET/
It query all the business units in a specific BIM 360 account with id and name and path.